# Number of Observations in ggplot R

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I output each of boxplot of my response variable with respect to my categorical feautures but I cannot highlight number of observations of each category. I tried stat_summary and geom_text() options which are stated here but they are not working.

How can I show them in my boxplots?

Below is my code:

```
    for(i in 3:ncol(Train_factor)){
    b<-paste("Boxplot for",colnames(Train_factor[i]))
    p10 <- (ggplot(data=Train_factor, aes_string(x = names(Train_factor)[i], 
    y = "Response",fill=variable)) +
    geom_boxplot())
    plot_list[[i]] = p10
    }
    for (i in 3:ncol(Train_factor)) {
    file_name = paste("boxplot", i, ".tiff", sep="")
    tiff(file_name)
    print(plot_list[[i]])
    dev.off()
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't provided a reproducible example, so here's a generic example using the built-in `mtcars` data frame. We use `geom_text()` but instead of `stat="identity"` (the default) we use `stat="count"` and `label=..count..` (which is the internally calculated count of the number of values) so that the displayed value will be the count of values.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, (aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(aes(label=..count..), y=0, stat='count', colour="red", size=4) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,max(mtcars$mpg))) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]